# EF6 Child Relations not Present in T4 on Query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, t4

I'm using Entity Framework 6 with a pretty simply DB using a repository pattern.  From previous versions EF I never had any problems retrieving child entities as part of my POCO objects.

For example if I have a Customer table and an account table where there is a 1-n relationship on the db, when I query the customer entity I would expect the customer entity to contain an array of Account entities, it never does, the array is always empty.

My queries are like:

```
dataContext.Set<TBL_CUSOTOMER>().Find(id)
```

Where dataContext is inheritted from DbContext.

I'm pretty sure I'm missing really obvious

Answer (score 1):

It should work

```
dataContext.Set<TBL_CUSTOMER>().Include(x=>x.accounts).FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id==id);
```

Comment: Almost, you can't use find with include so it had to be SingleOrDefault